# Why is my sprite constant in mint language?

Tags: mit-scratch

[image: Code]

He only moves a little bit and not moves forever

Comment: The solution is in the last word of your question: use the 'forever' block. It's in the brown 'control' group.

Answer (score 0):

The (move 10 steps) block will only move your player by a tiny bit. It moves in the direction that your sprite is facing.

If you would like to have it moving for a longer period of time, (and smoother), I'd recommend  using a loop of some kind.

Putting a Forever() loop around it will have it always move forward.

Repeat(number of times to repeat) will move it forward however many times you want.

Try to experiment with more of these loops and see which one best fits your project and goals.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options. The first is to put the 'move 10 steps' block into a forever loop, so you code goes like the first one in the image and that will make your sprite move 10 blocks until the stop button is pressed.
Or alternatively, you could use a repeat (no. of times to repeat) block, like the second one:

[Two Block Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL9iw.png)

That's all!